# Adding related products with a reciprocal link

Tags: magento2, product

I am looking for a plugin that will automatically add a reciprocal link to a product that is manually added as a related or associated product.
I.e. Add product B to product A, product A is automatically added to product B.
Can anyone recommend a plugin to generate auto crosslinking for related products?